# Python Process fails map() silently

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When assigning tasks to `ProcessPoolExecutor` using `.map()`, any failures in mapping are swallowed silently. Is there anyway to force a compile error?

Simplest way to replicate:

```
def hello(x):
    print("hello", x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [x for x in range(10)]
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as ppe:
        ppe.map(hello) # Missing one parameter here, but no error reported!!!
    print("bye")
```

Prints out:

```
bye <<< No errors!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not missing any arguments. The signature of [`.map`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) is

```
def map(self, fn, *iterables, timeout=None, chunksize=1):
```

and you're leaving `*iterables` empty, leaving no work to be done – this is what `map` does internally:

```
fs = [self.submit(fn, *args) for args in zip(*iterables)]
```

If you do pass in more arguments than the function accepts, you do get an error:

```
for x in ppe.map(hello, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]):
```

...

```
TypeError: hello() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: However, when the child process tries to execute hello without the parameter, wouldn't the execution fail? i.e., TypeError: hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
Does this happen at compile time? There is no runtime error even without the argument?

Comment: A: python is interpreted -> there is no compile time. B: what happens if you run `for i in range(0)`? `hello()` is never called.

Comment: It never tries to execute anything without a parameter since there are no sets of parameters.